# Decision tree algorithms in Python

Tags: python, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I wanted to classify a few datasets with ID3, C4.5, CHAID and CART Decision Trees, but the sklearn library only uses the CART and ID3 algorithms (by changing the 'criterion' parameter). Could anyone suggest reliable ways in which I can use the other algorithms to classify my datasets?

Comment: Do you want to use other Classification algorithms ?

Comment: If you are interested in other than decision trees algorithms, for example, linear models, random forest, extra trees, xgboost, catboost, lightgbm, neural networks then you can try MLJAR [AutoML](https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised) open-source python package